# Groovy/Java - Issue copying files with parentheses in its path

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I currently have a script that copies files from a source directory to a target directory through regex inclusions and exclusions, however when the path contains parentheses the file will not copy.

My initial thought was that the issue was with how source and target were being read since ( is a special character, to combat that I've tried to replace the ( with an escaped (, but I may have been doing that portion wrong.

```
import groovy.io.FileType
import java.nio.file.*

    String Source = 'C:/temp/file(s)'
    String Target = 'C:/newTemp/file(s)'

    String InclusionsRegexes = "garbage.txt"

    String ExclusionsRegexes = ""

    class RegexInfo
    {
        private String AllRegexes = "";

        public RegexInfo(String RegexString, String RegexType, String Source)
        {
            if(RegexString != null)
            {
                def RegexArray = RegexString.split(",");

                for(item in RegexArray)
                {
                    String fullRegexPath = Source + "/" + item;

                    if(AllRegexes != null && !AllRegexes.isAllWhitespace())
                    {
                        //Add regex value for Or
                        AllRegexes += "|";
                    }
                    AllRegexes += fullRegexPath;
                }
            }
        }
        public String getAllRegexes() { return this.AllRegexes; }
    }

    IncludesRegexInfo = new RegexInfo(InclusionsRegexes, "inclusion", Source);
    ExcludesRegexInfo = new RegexInfo(ExclusionsRegexes, "exclusion", Source);

    File SourceDirToCopy = new File(Source);

    SourceDirToCopy.eachFileRecurse()
    {
        SourceFile ->

        String SourceFilePath = SourceFile.toString().replaceAll("\\\\","/");

        if(SourceFile.isDirectory())
        {
            SourceFilePath += "/"
        }

        if(SourceFilePath.matches(IncludesRegexInfo.getAllRegexes()) && !SourceFilePath.matches(ExcludesRegexInfo.getAllRegexes()))
        {
            File TargetFile = new File(SourceFilePath.replace(Source, Target))
            String TargetFilePath = TargetFile.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "/");

                if(!TargetFile.getParentFile().exists())
                {
                    TargetFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()
                }
                Files.copy(SourceFile.toPath(), TargetFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            }
        }
    }
```

The errors I've been receiving have been either unexpected characters or the file not moving without an error.

Comment: When running the script as is, there are no error messages. The file simply doesn't copy. I've been looking into it some more and it seems to occur in the ```SourceDirToCopy.eachFileRecurse()``` when "matching" the paths. Although a println would should that ```IncludesRegexInfo.getAllRegexes()``` and ```SourceFilePath``` would show the same value, when using a ```SourceFilePath.matches(IncludesRegexInfo.getAllRegexes) ```  the expression would evaluate to false.

Comment: just before `Files.copy` put the following assertions: `assert SourceFile.exists()` and `assert TargetFile.getParentFile().exists()`. then you'll see the error if source file of target folder does not exist. the error `unexpected characters` connected with wrong regular expression.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that it never makes it into that ```if(SourceFilePath.matches(IncludesRegexInfo.getAllRegexes() && !SourceFilePath.matches(ExcludesRegexInfo.getAllRegexes()))``` to do the assertions. If you do a ```println``` for  ```SourceFilePath``` and ```IncludesRegexInfo.getAllRegexes()``` you'll see that both of those values would be the same. However I think since the ```(``` is a special character for grouping in regex, it is somehow affecting either of the two listed variables.

Comment: so, what's your question? do you need help with regex?

Comment: I guess so, or at least how to replace that special character ```(``` with the escaped version of it. I've tried replacing it with the following line of code ```SourceFilePath.replaceAll("\\(",Matcher.quoteReplacement('('))``` but I'm not sure if I'm selecting what I want to replace correctly.

Comment: i think you have to ask another question and provide what you have (input data), what you want to achieve, and what you've tried. make your non-working code simple, so anybody could help you.

Comment: I mean my post already encompasses the question I asked, i.e. the second paragraph. Plus the code I provided also has all of the input data and has been slimmed down to show how exactly it works and where I believe it needs to be edited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the issue of the script not copying, there was an issue with `if(SourceFilePath.matches(IncludesRegexInfo.getAllRegexes() && !SourceFilePath.matches(ExcludesRegexInfo.getAllRegexes()))` when "matching" the two strings.

The strings read as the same lines however did not match in terms of regex. To fix this you must escape the `(` and `)` in the `ExcludesRegexInfo.getAllRegexes()`. This was done with an `.replaceAll("\\(","\\\\(").replaceAll("\\)","\\\\)")`